# pandas HDF5 numpy created dataframe cannot use .head() or display(df)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, h5py

I extract numpy data (all non-zero floats) from a HDF5 file, then cast it into a pandas dataframe and then I try to show the data inside, but this is failing. I do all this in a Jupyter Notebook.

```
import h5py  # necessary for storing
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display, HTML

h5 = h5py.File('some_file')
predict = h5['path/to/dataset']  # get dataset reference
predict = predict[:]  # load all float data into Numpy array
col_names = [1, 2, 3]

pred_df = pd.DataFrame(data=predict, index=predict, columns=col_names)
# this works
act_df.describe()

# these don't
display(pred_df)
pred_df.head(5)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
Use a.any() or a.all()
```

It seems my DataFrame is somehow wrongly created, but I don't understand why.

## Solution (thanks to con--)

Remove `, index=predict`  -->

```
pred_df = pd.DataFrame(data=predict, columns=col_names)
```

## Bonus

If you get the following error after loading your dataset from a HDF5 file:

```
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

It means you forgot to do:

```
predict = predict[:]  # load all float data into Numpy array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issues is that you set index to predict. You probably want to leave index alone and have pandas create it for you. You're trying to select the first 5 elements in the index, but the index isn't whole numbers, it's the dataset of floats you loaded.